# Show/Hide Div with JQuery using one Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I've added a promobar in WordPress using a plugin and it has a lick "+" and "x" to hide/show the entire bar (This is it: https://wp-me.com). Then I've copied it to Blogger and it is working well here: http://www.tatweir.com

the problem is with Blogger now, as I want to add a similar "+" & "x" to the bar to give the visitor ability to hide/show the bar (Exactly the same as WordPress).

This is the Code I'm currently using in Blogger:

```
<div class='tatweir_bar' style='background-color: #006991; color: #ffffff; width:100%; text-align: center; z-index: 9999999999;'>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .tatweir_bar { top: 0px; position: fixed; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
        .tatweir_bar .tatweir_bar-container { width: 100%; font-size: 18px; position: relative;
                                              margin-right: auto;
                                              margin-left: auto;
                                              max-width: 100%;
                                              padding: 10px 60px;
                                              line-height: 1.4;}
        .tatweir_bar a { color: #00dbaf;}
        .tatweir_bar .tatweir_bar-button { color: #fff; background-color: #00dbaf; margin: .2em .5em;     display: inline-block;
                                           padding: 6px 10px;
                                           font-size: 12px;
                                           border-radius: 3px;
                                           color: #fff!important;
                                           outline: 0;
                                           border: 0;
                                           cursor: pointer;
                                           text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
        </style>
        <div class='tatweir_bar-container-outer'>
        <div class='tatweir_bar-container tatweir_bar-clearfix'>
            <div class='tatweir_bar-button-type tatweir_bar-content'>
                <span class='tatweir_bar-text'>عرض خاص لفتره محدودة: احصل على استضافة من  <strong>بلوهوست</strong> بسعر <strong>$3.45 شهريا&#1611;</strong> بدلا&#1611; من <del>$7.99</del>.  </span><a class='tatweir_bar-button' href='https://wp-me.com/offer/bluehost' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>إحصل على الخصم الآن</a></div>                                 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below updated HTML, CSS and JS (make sure to use jQuery).
And, fiddle.

I hope this could help you.

HTML

```
<div id="notificationDiv" class='tatweir_bar down'>
    <div class='tatweir_bar-container-outer notification_content'>
        <div class='tatweir_bar-container tatweir_bar-clearfix'>
            <div class='tatweir_bar-button-type tatweir_bar-content'>
                <span class='tatweir_bar-text notification_text'>عرض خاص لفتره محدودة: احصل على استضافة من  <strong>بلوهوست</strong> بسعر <strong>$3.45 شهريا&#1611;</strong> بدلا&#1611; من <del>$7.99</del>.  </span>
                <a class='tatweir_bar-button notification_button' href='https://wp-me.com/offer/bluehost' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>إحصل على الخصم الآن</a>
            </div>                                 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="notification_close"><span> + </span></div>
    <div id="notification_open"> + </div>
</div>

<div id="bodyContent">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p><p>
        Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </p><p>
        Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
        </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            transition: padding-top ease 0.3s, padding-bottom ease 0.3s;
        }

        #bodyContent {
             box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #notificationDiv {
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            min-height: 30px;
            background-color: #006991; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            text-align: center; 
            z-index: 9999999999;
        }

         #notificationDiv.up{
            transform: translateY(-100%) translate3d(0,0,0);
            transition: transform ease 0.3s;
        }

         #notificationDiv.down{
            transform: translateY(0%) translate3d(0,0,0);
            transition: transform ease 0.3s;
        }
        #notification_open, #notification_close {
            position: absolute;
        }

        #notification_close {
            right: 30px;
            top: 50%;    
            height: 8px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #e9f7fd;
            font-size: 22px;
            line-height: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #notification_close span{
             transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
             display: block
        }

          #notification_close:hover {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #00dbaf;
        }

         #notification_open{
            right: 20px;
            bottom: -38px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: #006991;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .notification_content{
             margin-right: auto;
             margin-left: auto;
             cursor: pointer;
        }

        .notification_button {
            background-color: #00dbaf;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 6px 10px;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #fff;
            outline: 0;
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            text-decoration: none;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .notification_text {
            color: #fff;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin: .2em .5em;
        }      

         .tatweir_bar { 
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        }

         .tatweir_bar .tatweir_bar-container { 
                                                width: 100%; 
                                                font-size: 18px; 
                                                position: relative;
                                                margin-right: auto;
                                                margin-left: auto;
                                                max-width: 100%;
                                                padding: 10px 60px;
                                                line-height: 1.4;
                                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                            }
          .tatweir_bar a { 
                            color: #00dbaf;
                         }
          .tatweir_bar .tatweir_bar-button { 
                                               color: #fff; 
                                               background-color: #00dbaf; 
                                               margin: .2em .5em;     
                                               display: inline-block;
                                               padding: 6px 10px;
                                               font-size: 12px;
                                               border-radius: 3px;
                                               color: #fff!important;
                                               outline: 0;
                                               border: 0;
                                               cursor: pointer;
                                               text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

                                            }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('body').css('padding-top', $("#notificationDiv").height());
     $("#notification_open").hide();

    $("#notification_open").click(function () {
        $('body').css('padding-top', $("#notificationDiv").height());
        $("#notification_close").show();
        $("#notificationDiv").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#notification_close").click(function () {
        $('body').css('padding-top', '0px');
        $("#notification_open").show();
        $("#notificationDiv").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/8e991smf/
```

Comment: This is a Blogger blog.
I just need a JQuery code and the updated HTML code.

Comment: Many thanks @Guruling-Kumbhar for the updated code. I've added it, but the show/hide links doesn't work! see this please: http://hosting.tatweir.com   and again thanks for help.

Comment: After debugging ur code, I found that you have added given JS code before JQuery.  kindly include it after Jquery.

Comment: Yes, I've added it to the end of the template and it is working now. Many thanks for ur help!